# Using intrinsics in their own initialisation

Tags: c++, c, sse, avx

I have a piece of code that does this:

```
__m128i a = _mm_loadl_pi(a, (__m64 *)ptr);
```

Where ptr is some memory address. I get a compiler warning about `a` being used in its own initialisation. Essentially what I wanted to do was just set the lower two elements and set the upper two elements later.

Is this kosher/will it cause problems later?

Comment: Use of uninitialized variable is always UB.

Comment: This is what [`_mm_undefined_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=2912,5562&text=undefined_ps) is for (but it only actually helps code-gen with Intel's compiler).  And besides that, **you want a `movsd` load of two floats that zero-extends and breaks the false dependency on the old value of a register, not a `movlps` that merges.**  Cast to `double *` and use `_mm_load_sd`